none of my boyfriends [has] complained
Scenario #1:
John is Sarah's new boyfriend who's never eaten food that she makes. She says that she's going to make him dinner. He asks her if she cooks well, and she responds:
1. I've had a lot of relationships in my life, and none of my boyfriends has complained about the quality of the food that I've made.
Scenario #2:
She's made him dinner. They sit down at the table and start eating. Halfway through, John says the food is off. Sarah looks at him in surprise and says:
2. I've had a lot of relationships in my life, and none of my boyfriends complained about the quality of the food that I made.
Question:
In scenario #1, it's true at the time of speaking that none of Sarah's boyfriends (including John) has complained about the quality of her food. Hence sentence #1 with "has complained" and "have made".
In scenario #2, it's no longer true at the time of speaking that none of Sarah's boyfriends has complained about the quality of her food: her previous boyfriends didn't, but John now has. Hence sentence #2 with "complained" and "made".
Is my reasoning correct, or would you use sentence #1 in both scenarios? Thank you.

"None of my previous boyfriends complained...". When he says the food is 'off', does he mean that the meat is no longer fresh (which could be a health issue), or just that he doesn't like it?

@KateBunting Thanks for the response, Kate. The food is fresh. He just doesn't like it.

@MichaelHarvey Thanks for the explanation, Michael. You said "...we prefer the past perfect...". Did you mean to say "... we prefer the present perfect..."? "Has complained" and "I've made" are in the present perfect.

I'm British too, and I wouldn't keep repeating Present Perfect in the cited context. I wouldn't bother with so many verbs in the first place, so I'd just end with my cooking rather than the food that I['ve] made. Once the first Present Perfect verb has been used to "set the scene", there's no need to repeat it, but I'd include ever for emphasis: I've had a lot of relationships in my life, and none of my boyfriends ever complained about the quality of my cooking. The "two scenarios" are irrelevant to my choice of verb form(s). It''s the same assertion both times.

I would use I've had a lot of relationships in my life, and, until today, none of my boyfriends has complained about the quality of the food that I've made._  That may be because I'm British, and we very often use the present perfect to speak about a past action that we consider relevant to the present. The present perfect can be used in the same way in American English, but people often use the past simple as in your scenario (2) when they consider the action finished.

The boyfriend is a dick, and should soon be an ex-boyfriend.

No, the food was actually "off".  John will soon keel over. The reason that none of her previous boyfriends ever complained is that the poison for some reason was slower-acting on John. They succumbed immediately.

:-) Tim is making the point that describing food as off usually means that it's starting to go bad - hence my question.

@KateBunting -I talked to an American friend about food 'going off' and she said 'Off? Off what?'.

@KateBunting Can someone say "The food is off." meaning that they don't like it, or is it not used that way? I've heard people say something like "The sentence sounds off to me.", in which case they mean that they don't like the way the sentence sounds. I thought I could apply this analogy and use the preposition "off" the same way when talking about food.

I think "The sentence sounds off to me" means that it doesn't sound natural or correct rather than that the speaker 'dislikes' it.  Similarly, if an item of food is 'off' there is something wrong with it - at least to my British ears (see Michael's comment above). I would never understand "This food is off" to mean "I personally don't like it" - hence my question to you.

prof1589 - if someone says 'there is something off' with e.g. a story, an explanation, a report, in fact something written or said, they don't mean merely that they 'don't like it'. They mean that they think that there may be something objectively wrong with the thing that was said or written - a statement may be false or inconsistent, an explanation can be invented or stupid, or contain errors of grammar or logic. Like food that has a slight smell which tells you that you probably shouldn't eat it. Or milk that has 'turned'.  We have an idiom, to 'smell a rat' (like a dog does).

@KateBunting - my American friend said that when she returned to California her friends and family kept looking oddly at her, or asking what she meant, because she had picked up so many British idioms in six months.

Dear Prof1589 - I know that your examples are purely invented to discuss verb tenses, but you should know that many people in English-speaking countries  will see the situations depicted (new boyfriend, first meal, already moaning; woman being cook and maid for a man) as deeply sexist or misogynist. The fact that you seem to see them as 'everyday' is oddly disturbing.

To answer the question more seriously than I do in my comment, you're omitting  words that would typically be used in such a statement:

None of my  previous boyfriends ever complained ...

Since John is at that moment a boyfriend,  a robot overhearing that conversation in the year 2085 might melt down and start smoking because of the paradox.  But if the robot knows what previous and ever mean, that shouldn't happen.
And even if those words aren't used, speech is contextual, and utterances are to be construed in light of the context.
